# cordova sqlite join query not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

This query is not working in cordova sqlite :

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT *
                     FROM cc_user_complaint_status 
                     INNER JOIN cc_manage_departments ON
                     cc_user_complaint_status.department_id = cc_manage_departments.dep_id",[], user_success, user_error);
```

Comment: Define "not working". Share any error messages you are receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can show answer that post here Example..

[sql, sqlite SELECT with inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821920/sql-sqlite-select-with-inner-join)

Example:

```
SELECT doctors.doctor_id,doctors.doctor_name,visits.patient_name             
FROM doctors  
INNER JOIN visits          
ON doctors.doctor_id=visits.doctor_id  
WHERE doctors.degree='MD';
```

Comment: its help then you can make ans. correct and uproot.