# Sql Join two table and show the table which has null values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, null

I have two tables which i have done inner join and i want to show those rows which has price, sale_price, stock_unit fields are null or i have not inserted those price, sale_price, stock_unit.

```
$live_query = "select shower.id,  shower.name, shower.firstimage,shower_pricing.price,  shower_pricing.list_id, shower_pricing.sale_price,shower_pricing.discount,shower_pricing.stock_unit
from shower
inner join shower_pricing
on shower.id=shower_pricing.id 
where shower_pricing.price,shower_pricing.sale_price,shower_pricing.stock_unit is null";
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cordova sqlite join query not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712727/cordova-sqlite-join-query-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying all those records in shower which does not have an equivalent in shower_pricing and querying those records which do have an entry in shower_pricing but the given attributes i.e. price, sale_price, stock_unit fields are two different cases.

Items having no entry in shower_pricing

```
$live_query = "select shower.id,  shower.name, shower.firstimage,shower_pricing.price,  
shower_pricing.list_id, shower_pricing.sale_price,shower_pricing.discount,
shower_pricing.stock_unit
from shower
left join shower_pricing
on shower.id=shower_pricing.id 
where shower_pricing.id is null;
```

Items having an entry but given attributes null

```
$live_query = "select shower.id,  shower.name, shower.firstimage,shower_pricing.price,  
shower_pricing.list_id, shower_pricing.sale_price,shower_pricing.discount,
shower_pricing.stock_unit
from shower
inner join shower_pricing
on shower.id=shower_pricing.id 
where shower_pricing.price is null OR shower_pricing.sale_price is null 
OR shower_pricing.stock_unit is null;
```

Comment: no issues :)
you use inner join when you are expecting results from both the tables therefore if you want to find those results which are present in table A but not in table B then inner join would not be the best choice. 
In such cases you can use left join, left join gives you all results of table A and only those of table B which corresponds table A's entries.

Answer (score 2):

SQL NULL's special, and you have to do `WHERE field IS NULL`, as NULL cannot be equal to anything, including itself (ie: NULL = NULL is always false).

Comment: Try: `where shower_pricing.price and shower_pricing.sale_price and shower_pricing.stock_unit IS NULL";`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a left outer join and not an inner join.

```
select 
    shower.id, shower.name, shower.firstimage,
    shower_pricing.price, shower_pricing.list_id, 
    shower_pricing.sale_price,shower_pricing.discount,
    shower_pricing.stock_unit
from shower left outer join shower_pricing 
    on shower.id=shower_pricing.id 
where shower_pricing.price is null 
    or shower_pricing.sale_price is null 
    or shower_pricing.stock_unit is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all of them to be NULL, Query should look something like this,

```
$live_query = "select shower.id,  shower.name, shower.firstimage,shower_pricing.price,  shower_pricing.list_id, shower_pricing.sale_price,shower_pricing.discount,shower_pricing.stock_unit
from shower
inner join shower_pricing
on shower.id=shower_pricing.id 
where shower_pricing.price IS NULL AND shower_pricing.sale_price IS NULL AND shower_pricing.stock_unit IS NULL";
```

If you want any of the value to be null, your query would look like this,

```
$live_query = "select shower.id,  shower.name, shower.firstimage,shower_pricing.price,  shower_pricing.list_id, shower_pricing.sale_price,shower_pricing.discount,shower_pricing.stock_unit
from shower
inner join shower_pricing
on shower.id=shower_pricing.id 
where shower_pricing.price IS NULL OR shower_pricing.sale_price IS NULL OR shower_pricing.stock_unit IS NULL";
```

Comment: now it is working i used inner join instead of left outer join.

Comment: select 
    shower.id, shower.name, shower.firstimage,
    shower_pricing.price, shower_pricing.list_id, 
    shower_pricing.sale_price,shower_pricing.discount,
    shower_pricing.stock_unit
from shower left outer join shower_pricing 
    on shower.id=shower_pricing.id 
where shower_pricing.price is null 
    or shower_pricing.sale_price is null 
    or shower_pricing.stock_unit is null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.firstimage, sp.price, sp.list_id, sp.sale_price, sp.discount, sp.stock_unit
FROM shower s 
INNER JOIN shower_pricing sp ON s.id = sp.id 
WHERE (sp.price IS NULL OR sp.price = '') 
  AND (sp.sale_price IS NULL OR sp.sale_price = '') 
  AND (sp.stock_unit IS NULL OR sp.stock_unit = '')
```