# INNER JOIN selects only one row from second table

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to get last value of the second table using mysql inner join.

This is my first table name 'tb_reg'

[image]

Second table 'tb_stud_qulification'

[image]

I want to get the last date of the 'candidate_no' where first table 'id' equqal to the second table 'candidate_no'.

I wrote inner join code like this but i'm getting error

```
SELECT reg.*, quli.course, quli.total_per 
FROM  tb_reg AS reg 
INNER JOIN tb_stud_qulification AS quli ON reg.stage = '2' AND reg.id = quli.candidate_no AND 
ORDER BY quli.id 
LIMIT 1
```

I would like to get the result like this
 [image]

Comment: Your join ends in "and", so that's not valid SQL

Comment: There is no date column in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

you can show:

```
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821920/sql-sqlite-select-with-inner-join`
```

example:

```
SELECT doctors.doctor_id,doctors.doctor_name,visits.patient_name             
FROM doctors  
INNER JOIN visits          
ON doctors.doctor_id=visits.doctor_id  
WHERE doctors.degree='MD';
```

Comment: Without degree specification i would like to get the last qualification(course) of the 'id'

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this (watch the different ON and WHERE clauses)

```
SELECT reg.*, quli.course, quli.total_per 
FROM  tb_reg AS reg 
INNER JOIN tb_stud_qulification AS quli ON reg.id = quli.candidate_no 
WHERE reg.stage = '2' 
ORDER BY quli.id 
LIMIT 1
```

but apart from that, I don't see a `stage` field in your `tb_reg` table...

Comment: Here i'm getting only 1 value, i want to get the 2 rows because 'id' is matching to two 'candidate_no' right? how to get the last candidate number value?

Comment: I suppose that would additionally require `GROUP BY quli.id` and NO `LIMIT` - but what about that `stage`?